# Give a dynamic value to trailing space of a UIView in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have two `UIViews` with parent and child relation to each other. I want to set a trailing space of `childView` to its `parentView` with unknown value. When i set the margin with constant value, it always place with that value but i need to place that with the value according to its width. How can i set constraint in `StoryBoard`? I can't set that again in program because i have more child views beside.

Comment: did u set constraints in storybaord ?

Comment: Thanks i have got my solution

Comment: @SyedeHussaini hi. Please post your answer here so that it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Approaches of achieving this..

1: create an object of your desired constraint using IBOutlet and change the value in the `ViewController.m` file.
for example..

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *trailingSpaceConstraint;
```

Now change the constant value to any desired number. In my case i want to set the trailing space to 3 times 1/4th of the screen width.

self.trailingSpaceConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height/4*3;

> 2: Select any constraint and navigate to property attribute and change the value according to Add Side Class Customization by clicking the + sign left to the constant field in that property attribute section of any constraint.

Comment: Can you explain more details about the second method?